# How do you get a global var to be instantiated as the very first thing in C++ under win32?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008, winapi

sI'm on Windows and I'm building a C++ project with VS2008.  I'm trying to replace new/delete/malloc/free etc.  Which is working i.e. my replacements are getting called.

However my replacement allocator needs to be initialised.  I have done this thus far by defining it as a global variable in a .cpp file with the #pragma init_seg(lib) defined inside it.

This worked up until recently when std::locale started to get initialised which was calling new before my allocator was getting initialised.  So I nervously moved my allocator's global variable to the compiler segment ie #pragma init_seg(compiler).

This worked for a bit and then I decided to override malloc.  Now I get a malloc call in __crtGetStringTypeA_stat in _tmainCRTStartup which is before even the global vars in the compiler segment have been initialised.

Is there any way to get my variable be instantiated before the CRT start up.  The only thing I can think of is rebuilding my crt lib and trying some how to insert my initialisation code in there some where.  I presume there must be a crt clean up function as well?

Is there an easier route to this and/or something obvious I'm missing here?

Comment: Don't use a global variable is my recommendation.

Comment: @DeadMG: I doubt you can write a memory allocator as a replacement for `malloc` without *any* global variables.

Comment: @Andre, That depends on if you call file-static variables or variables in an anonymous namespace 'global'... And of course there's also function-scope statics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using a `static storage duration` object.

But you are having problems with the order of initialization.
To solve this use a static storage duration object that is defined within a function scope.

```
MyAllocator& getAllocator()
{
    static  MyAllocator  allocator;  // Note the static here.
                                     // It has the appropriate lifespan and will be destoryed.
                                     // and is automatically constructed the first time this
                                     // function is called.
    return allocator;
}
```

Now your versions of new/delete/ etc can get a reference to the allocator by calling getAllocator(). This will guarantee that the object is correctly initialized (assuming MyAllocator has the correct constructor).

Comment: Note that this is not safe if it's possible for multiple threads to race for initialization

Comment: @bdonlan: insert a call as the first line of `main()`, unless you can come up with a scheme to start threads before execution of `main()` begins.

Comment: @Andre, easy, just have some random DLL start up a thread in its DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH handler.

Comment: @bdonlan: He is crashing before main is entered. Therefore there are zero threads (apart from main). Therefore it is **absolutely safe** in the given context of the question. Also it is relatively trivial to make it thread safe. anybody starting threads in an the attach handler has much bigger problems.

Comment: @Martin, there can indeed be threads before main is entered, if there are some misbehaving DLLs linked in (and there is a lot of misbehaving software on Windows to deal with :), or static constructors creating threads for some reason, or some program doing dll injection prior to main, or...

Comment: @bdonlan: Actually there can not. The windows threads libraries specifically say this is not allowed and undefined behavior (as do all (that I have read) threading libraries). Thus threads before main is UB and thus you have bigger problems.

Comment: @Martin, that may be so, but that doesn't preclude someone from trying it anyway. I guess what it boils down to is - is this code intended only for the OP's program, or will the OP be hooking third-party apps and DLLs? If the latter, he needs to be prepared to deal with a certain degree of misbehaving applications, and using `InitOnceExecuteOnce` may be warranted.

Comment: @bdonlan: If we are in UB (for whatever reason including naughty thread startup). Then there is no guarantee that InitOnceExecuteOnce() will work as expected.

Comment: Would other DLLs even care? They're going to link (either statically or dynamically) against the normal `malloc` from the CRT. And you get major ugliness when passing memory across DLL boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

On windows, you can use `InitOnceExecuteOnce` to initialize your allocator. For example:

```
static INIT_ONCE initFlag = INIT_ONCE_STATIC_INIT;

static BOOL CALLBACK InitMyHeap(PINIT_ONCE InitOnce, PVOID Parameter, PVOID *Context)
{
    *Context = (PVOID)CreateMyHeap();
}

MyHeap *GetMyHeap()
{
    PVOID vpMyHeap;
    if (!InitOnceExecuteOnce(&initFlag, InitMyHeap, NULL, *vpMyHeap)) {
        abort();
    }
    return (MyHeap *)vpMyHeap;
}
```

With this, your heap will be initialized exactly once, after `GetMyHeap()` is called. Your `new`/`delete`/`malloc` overrides should then call `GetMyHeap()` to obtain a pointer to the heap structure (or to simply ensure the heap is initialized). This is safe even with multiple threads, and even if it occurs before CRT initialization, as `initFlag` is static data in your data segment, and does not require a constructor call.

Note, of course, that `CreateMyHeap()` must be careful not to make use of CRT services; directly call into Windows DLL functions (ie, `kernel32.dll` and friends) only.